# eclipse find possible code path between two functions

Tags: eclipse

I have a question about eclipse. maybe it is not possible, but i still want to confirm with experts :) 
   In my context, i use C.but may apply to java and other lanuages.

say i have a really large project. and i have a function A , and a function B. 
   Is there a way i can tell if there is a code path from function A to function B or function B.
 say A -> D -> C- > E->F->B

i know there is call heirachy. but my project is soo big. function A is not directly calling B. function A is called by like 10 places and there 10 callers are called by another 100 callers. 
  so is there a feature in eclipse to flood the code path and find the connection between the two functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call this a good way, but it may be a useful way for some.  To start with, you can create an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script as below.  `#v` represents the key combo <kbd>Win+v</kbd> to trigger it.

```
#v::Send {Right}{Down}{Right}{Down}{Right}{Down}{Right}{Down}
```

You may want to repeat a few more times (or many many more times, I did).  Open the call hierarchy in Eclipse, select the first entry, and press <kbd>Win+v</kbd> and watch a few expand.  After you get them all (have fun), then you can right click on an entry and select `Copy Expanded Hierarchy`.  Paste it somewhere and search for the other function you are wanting to find the connection to.

I'll let you know if I find a 'real' solution.  If your project is (yeah, I know it's been a long time) big on the order of mine or more, then you may get fed up as Eclipse slows down with the spectacularly large tree.  Or perhaps it has just halted now...